# Parsing complex table with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to parse this webpage https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=787150 using jsoup in java.

But I am facing the issue of parsing the table that tag with edit_form.

Comment: What is your trial code and what is the part of the web page you try on it

Comment: I am trying to parse the edit_form table

Comment: You should use the API if possible: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:REST_API

Comment: @JonasCz or better yet, a Java API constructed on top of it, like [B4J](http://download.ralph-schuster.eu/eu.ralph-schuster.b4j/STABLE/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to select the table with `edit_form` class name.

```
try
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=787150").get();
    System.out.println("doc"+doc.select("form[id$=changeform]").select("table.edit_form"));

}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: thank you , but does not give me the edit_form, how ever I am able to retrieve the edit_form, my question is how to parse this form extract all the information in it.

Comment: Is that what you want?

Comment: I can retrive the table but I cannot parse it.

Comment: What you mean by parse,?  I don't  understand what you want exactly

Comment: What information a title a hyperlink a text?  the table contains different type of attributes